# python label expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser

Can't get advanced python label expression to work.  I am trying to get my if else expression to either concatenate or not based on if two fields are blank or not.

If SUB_UNIT_TYPE and SUB_UNIT_ID are not null then concatenate them together on a new line with a space between the values from the two fields.  I can't get python to find the null value.

I tried all the suggestions from this post.  [Using if/elif for passing null values to Python of label expression in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114471/using-if-elif-for-passing-null-values-to-python-of-label-expression-in-arcgis-fo)

```
def FindLabel ( [Add_Num], [PROP_UNIT_TYPE], [PROP_UNIT_ID],[Sub_Unit_Type],[Sub_Unit_ID]):
   if (not([SUB_UNIT_TYPE] is None) and not([SUB_UNIT_ID] is None)):
       L = ([Add_Num] +  '\n' + [Sub_Unit_Type] + [Sub_Unit_ID])
   else:
      L = ([Add_Num])
   return L
```

Tried this.  Still need to add a space between the four subaddress fields and write an elif statement for if the PROP_UNIT_TYPE and PROP_UNIT_ID is null but the SUB_UNIT_TYPE and SUB_UNIT_ID fields are not null.  Is this really the best way to go?  Its easier in C# and SQL Server but python is pretty much the only language accepted in labeling expressions.

```
def FindLabel ( [Add_Num], [PROP_UNIT_TYPE], [PROP_UNIT_ID], [Sub_Unit_Type], [Sub_Unit_ID]):
   if ([PROP_UNIT_TYPE] is None and [PROP_UNIT_ID] is None and [SUB_UNIT_TYPE] is None and [SUB_UNIT_ID] is None):
      L = ([Add_Num])
   else:
      L = '{0}\n{1}{2}\n{3}{4}'.format([Add_Num],[PROP_UNIT_TYPE],[PROP_UNIT_ID],[Sub_Unit_Type],[Sub_Unit_ID])
   return L
```

Comment: the `L` in the `if` is at a different indent to the `L` in `else`

Comment: I think Add_Num or Sub_Unit_ID is a numeric object and you can't concatenate numbers and strings.. try '{0}\n{1} {2}'.format([Add_Num],[Sub_Unit_Type],[Sub_Unit_ID]) it's a little more robust for types. Nice catch @Midavalo, I didn't even see that until you pointed it out.. this is why I TAB indent, spaces are so easy to get wrong by 1 and not even see.

Comment: Not sure @MichaelMiles-Stimson I think on label expression all variables get cast as strings.

Comment: Interesting @PolyGeo, I'll try that out. I always assumed that the variable types were the field types.. not that types are all that rigid in python with its 'duck type' variables. Update: you are absolutely correct,  return '{0} {1}'.format(type( [File]), type([FID])) returns <type 'unicode'> <type 'unicode'> so variables are converted to strings for the purposes of label expressions... well *I've* learned a new thing today! This just proves that assumptions aren't always correct.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson "Field values are automatically cast to text strings" from http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000027000000

Comment: So what is it actually doing?  Your label expression works fine for me as is

Comment: Answered. Thank you all. I am just trying to learn enough python to get the job done.